# Python flask and systemd

Tags: python, systemd

I have a python program which has something like:

```
from flask import Flask, abort
```

and I made this as a systemd service (called as `test_flask.service`) as:

```
[Unit]
Description=My simple flask service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=export PYTHONPATH=<path_to_the_python_directory>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 <path_to_the_python_directory>/test_flask.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start this using `sudo systemctl start test_flask.service`
I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the status of your service, you'd have seen something like this:

```
Sep 19 17:46:10 muru-1604 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/foo.service:7] Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: export PYTHONPATH=/some/path
```

The `Environment` setting is not using shell syntax. All it accepts is simple assignment:

```
Environment=PYTHONPATH=/some/path
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..However I still have the same error even after doing Environment=PYTHONPATH=/some/path

Comment: @srinidhikasagar then it's a Python issue; you should try running the script with a clean environment and see what you need to set for it to run